# How can this formula be reached from the Euler Lagrange equation?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

In some lecture slides for a class I am taking, this is stated:

[image]

I don't see how this is true. The E-L equation merely tells us that at extrema (i.e. the minimum, which is an attained infimum):

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}$$

At most I would get that:

$$\int \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} dx = \int\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} dx$$

Which is:

$$\int \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} dx = \frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} + C$$

Where are $v$ and $f$ coming from? How is the expression being put in terms of a single integral? Why doesn't $\bar{y}$ show up in this expression ?

I am very lost. This is the only slide related to the topic, the class has no book and due to covid, things are online, but my internet isn't great and I already suffer from attention problems, so I have not been able to follow the material very well.

Answer (score 1):

Take your Euler Lagrange equation and multiply by $v(x)$. Now integrate both sides and use integration by parts on the right side.